# Конвертировать string в число

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Пытаюсь достать цену из корзины покупки.
Сама цена: 22,99 €

```
var getPrice = document.querySelector('.price');
var price = getPrice.querySelector('.regular').innerText;
 console.log(price);
var parsePrice = parseFloat(price);
 console.log(parsePrice);
```

Выход: 22

Необходимо, чтобы цена выходила такая же, но без знака евро.

Подскажите какой метод можно использовать в данном случае.

Comment: Сначала заменить запятую на точку, а потом парсить. Но вообще идея парсить html так себе. Лучше бы хранить эти данные в каком-то другом месте и сразу в правильном формате

Comment: Разделителем целой и дробной части в javascript является точка.

Comment: если изменение разметки возможно, то убрать валюту(например в псевдоэлемент after), если не возможно, вырезать валюту из полученной строки через `replace` p.s. предварительно обработать некорректный разделитель целой и дробной части как выше написал @Grundy

Comment: @Bald, Спасибо за ответ. Это действительно помогло.